# SQL query 'where' not working as I expect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm very new to scripting and SQL and I've inherited a crazy database generated by some contact management software.  I'm running Microsoft SQL Server 2005.  What I'm trying to do is select rows that meet certain conditions (the most important being that BIRTHDATE is today's date, which seems like it may be my issue).  Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
  TBL_CONTACT.BIRTHDATE, 
  TBL_CONTACT.COMPANYNAME, 
  TBL_CONTACT.CATEGORY, 
  CUST_ContactTable1_074000.CUST_DesignatedAgent_074203199, 
  TBL_EMAIL.ADDRESS 
FROM 
  TBL_CONTACT, 
  CUST_ContactTable1_074000,
  TBL_EMAIL
WHERE 
  TBL_CONTACT.BIRTHDATE >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND 
  TBL_CONTACT.BIRTHDATE < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 1) AND 
  TBL_CONTACT.CATEGORY = 'Active' AND TBL_EMAIL.ADDRESS IS NOT NULL AND 
  CUST_ContactTable1_074000.CUST_DesignatedAgent_074203199 IS NOT NULL
```

The issue is that it's returning all the rows in my database (minus the records not meeting the NOT NULL and CATEGORY = 'Active' conditions, it appears) even though there should be only one row that has the correct TBL_CONTACT.BIRTHDATE.  It is putting the BIRTHDATE of the only row that should work down the entire list, even though those rows should have BIRTHDATE's that aren't today's date.  If I make it so there are no BIRTHDATE's that match today's, nothing gets returned (which is what I expect).

What am I doing wrong?  Please explain your answer as I am looking to learn.  Thank you!

Comment: Format and indent your query properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where are your join conditions between table? 
As it stands, you have a [cross join a.k.a Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join)

```
...
FROM 
   TBL_CONTACT C
   JOIN
   CUST_ContactTable1_074000 CT ON C.Something = CT.Something
   JOIN
   TBL_EMAIL E ON C.Anotherthing = CT.Anotherthing
WHERE
   ...
```

Comment: Is what you suggested basically linking the different tables based off of a common unique identifier?  I'm sorry, I am incredibly new to this stuff.  What do I need to put in place of 'Something' and 'Anotherthing'? Whatever it is that I can use to tell it is the same record across the different tables? Keys?

Comment: yes, this is the point of JOINs. If you're that new, then I suggest basic research or training too

Comment: Thanks, man. I got it to work! I started maybe 6 hours ago, barely understanding even the concept of syntax (in general), and I can't afford schooling.  I ran into a wall and couldn't find what I needed to do without asking.  I learn best by diving in head-first, but once in a while I need direction.  Thank you for not being condescending.